# Crisis: Reconciliation macro - Excel 2010 hangs every time

Tags: excel, vba, crash, excel-2010

Good evening.

Two months ago I started developing a macro in Excel 2010 with the purpose of reconciling two different sets of information. I put the project on hold a month ago, at which point the macro could chew through every row of information without any complaints.

A few days ago I resumed my work on the project, and I implemented some very minor use of long-arrays to contain the positions of rows that meet specific criteria. This has now resulted in the hair-tearing experience of having Excel hang on me every, single time I try to run the macro. Stepping through the code can be done without any issues, as long as I don't do it too fast, but the second I let it run on its own it crashes. A statusbar-update is part of the main loop, and it tells me that the macro manages to process approximately 1% of the rows before it stops responding.

This is an incredibly frustrating issue as it - as far as I know - simply shouldn't be happening and must be due to some limitation imposed upon Excel when it comes to handling large amounts of data. Maybe it interprets my loop as an infinite loop?

There is an over-arching loop which runs through one of the two datasets, and it contains a second loop which runs through relatively small parts of the second dataset to find matches. Before the crashes started happening the macro was capable of processing datasets roughly 11 times the size of the ones I am using now. Reducing the current size of the datasets to about 10% of the aforementioned default still results in the macro making Excel hang, but interestingly it manages to process 11% of the data. The sensible conclusion to draw from this is that there is an actual piece of data somewhere in the datasets which somehow is causing Excel to hang, but 1): I would expect an error message if this was the case, and 2) inspecting the datasets at around what constitutes the 1% has led to no extraordinary discoveries.

So I turn to you. I sincerely hope you can come with some suggestions as to what could be causing this and how I could attempt to fix it.

Here's the problematic sub-procedure: http://pastebin.com/ywacHTVN

I have been wondering if splitting it up into several sub-procedures would make it more digestible for Excel and thus resolve my problem? If this is the case, I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why.

Something important that I think I should mention: Earlier I wrote that the macro was capable of crunching through datasets 11 times larger than the current ones without any issues, before I implemented the minor usage of arrays. But this was only after I added regular executions - every time the StatusBar is updated - of DoEvents; before this was done, Excel would hang just like it is doing now.

```
Sub MainRecon()

Dim row_MSPS As Long, row_FPMS As Long, rowStart_FPMS As Long, rowEnd_FPMS As Long, row_FPMS_lastMatch As Long
Dim row_midFPMS As Long, row_midMSPS As Long, IMO_Number As Long, size_MSPS As Long, row_MSPS_next As Long
Dim n_matches As Integer, I_sup As Integer, temp_FPMS_Row As Long

Dim match_Array() As Long
Dim supreme_match_Array() As Long: ReDim supreme_match_Array(30)
Dim IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array() As Long: ReDim IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(30)

Dim row_first_FPMS As Integer, I As Integer, IMO_matches As Integer, supreme_Size As Integer

Dim order_no_FPMS As String

Dim match As Boolean, quantity_MSPS As Boolean, IMO_next_match As Boolean, stock_update As Boolean
Dim MSPS_duplicate As Boolean, FPMS_noMatches As Boolean, empty_FPMS As Boolean

Dim deliveryDate_MSPS As Date, deliveryDate_FPMS As Date, deliveryDate_MSPS_next As Date


row_MSPS = 2
row_FPMS = 2

row_midFPMS = 3
row_midMSPS = 3

size_MSPS = 2

'Index for supreme match array.
I_sup = 0

Do While MSPS_RawWS.Cells(size_MSPS, 1) <> ""
    size_MSPS = size_MSPS + 1
Loop


MainProcedure:
Do While MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 1) <> "" 'Stops at the end of the records

    'Boolean variables defined
    empty_FPMS = False
    match = False
    quantity_MSPS = False
    IMO_next_match = False
    stock_update = False
    FPMS_noMatches = False

    If IsNumeric(Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 2)) = True _
        And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 4, 2)) = True _
        And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 7, 4)) = True Then 'Confirms date format DD-MM-YYYY of 'Time for Bunker' of MSPS

        'Crew updated stock by reporting a new delivery instead of following proper procedure.
        'Stock-Delivery difference smaller than 60 will be picked up as a stock update
        'as well as delivery quantities under 10 [mt]
        If ((60 > Abs(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 6) - MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8)) And _
            Abs(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 6) - MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8)) >= 0) Or (0 < MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8) And MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8) <= 10)) And _
            (MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 6) + MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8) > 0) Then

                    MSPS_RawWS.Range("A" & row_MSPS, "H" & row_MSPS).Copy
                    mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midMSPS, 11).PasteSpecial

                    mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midMSPS, 9) = "Error 40. Updated stock reported as delivery."

                    row_midMSPS = row_midMSPS + 1
                    row_midFPMS = row_midFPMS + 1

                    Call UpdateProgress("", 4, row_MSPS, size_MSPS)


        Else 'Proceed if it passes the stock update check

            Call UpdateProgress("", 4, row_MSPS, size_MSPS)

            quantity_MSPS = False

            If MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8) > 0 Then 'If MSPS quantity is above 0, proceed

            quantity_MSPS = True

                If IsNumeric(Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 4, 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 7, 4)) = True Then 'Confirms date format DD-MM-YYYY

                deliveryDate_MSPS = Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 7), 10) 'Cuts away HH:MM:SS
                IMO_Number = MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 2)

                'Finds the next MSPS record with quantity and date.
                row_MSPS_next = row_MSPS + 1
                Do While (MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7) = "" Or Not MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 8) > 0) And row_MSPS_next <= size_MSPS _
                And Not (IsNumeric(Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 4, 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 7, 4)) = True)

                    row_MSPS_next = row_MSPS_next + 1

                Loop


                'Checks if the next MSPS record has an IMO that matches the current one, and gets the date of the next record
                IMO_next_match = False
                If IMO_Number = MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 2) And (IsNumeric(Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 4, 2)) = True _
                And IsNumeric(Mid(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 7, 4)) = True) And MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 8) > 0 Then

                    deliveryDate_MSPS_next = Left(MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 7), 10)
                    IMO_next_match = True

                End If

                'Checks if the MSPS record is a duplicate
                If IMO_next_match = True And deliveryDate_MSPS = deliveryDate_MSPS_next And _
                MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS, 8) = MSPS_RawWS.Cells(row_MSPS_next, 8) Then

                            MSPS_RawWS.Range("A" & row_MSPS, "H" & row_MSPS).Copy
                            mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midMSPS, 11).Paste

                            mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midMSPS, 9) = "Duplicate entry."

                            row_midMSPS = row_midMSPS + 1
                            row_midFPMS = row_midFPMS + 1

                            Call UpdateProgress("", 4, row_MSPS, size_MSPS)

                            row_MSPS = row_MSPS + 1

                            'Proceed prematurely to the next iteration in the all-encompassing 'Do While'-loop
                            'if the current MSPS-record is a duplicate
                            GoTo MainProcedure
                End If

                match = False
                row_first_FPMS = 0

                    Do While IsEmpty(FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1)) = False And (IMO_Number > FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1) _
                    Or IMO_Number = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1)) 'Search for FPMS records with matching IMO number

                        If IMO_Number = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1) Then

                            If row_first_FPMS > 0 Then
                                If FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_first_FPMS, 1) <> FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1) Then

                                    row_first_FPMS = row_FPMS 'This is the very first of the matching FPMS records
                                    'For use later in connection with the arrays.

                                End If

                            Else

                                row_first_FPMS = row_FPMS

                            End If


                            If deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) Or deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) - 1 Or deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) + 1 Then

                                match = True

                                Exit Do

                            End If
                        End If

                        row_FPMS = row_FPMS + 1

                    Loop

                If match = True Then

                'The following array will contain the location (row) of all FPMS records matching the current MSPS record
                ReDim match_Array(30)

                match_Array(0) = row_FPMS
                n_matches = 1

                row_FPMS_lastMatch = row_FPMS
                order_no_FPMS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 4)

                rowStart_FPMS = row_FPMS 'Multiple entries can exist in FPMS for a single entry in MSPS. This is the lower boundary

                row_FPMS = row_FPMS + 1

                Do While IMO_Number = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 1)

                    'The FPMS order numbers are made up of 8 ciphers: XXXXXXXN
                    'The 7 first ciphers are used to tie orders together. MSPS usually has a single entry for all FPMS
                    'entries under XXXXXXX.
                    If Left(order_no_FPMS, 7) = Left(FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 4), 7) And order_no_FPMS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 4) Then

                        match_Array(n_matches) = row_FPMS
                        n_matches = n_matches + 1

                        row_FPMS = row_FPMS + 1

                    ElseIf deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) Or deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) - 1 Or deliveryDate_MSPS = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) + 1 Then

                        match_Array(n_matches) = row_FPMS
                        n_matches = n_matches + 1

                        row_FPMS = row_FPMS + 1

                        'If the next valid MSPS record is on the date after the current one, and the next FPMS record is as well, exit loop
                        If IMO_next_match = True And deliveryDate_MSPS_next = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(row_FPMS, 5) Then

                            Exit Do

                        End If

                    End If
                    Loop

                    'Upper boundary of range.
                    rowEnd_FPMS = row_FPMS - 1

                    If n_matches = 1 Then

                        FPMS_RawWS.Range("A" & match_Array(0), "H" & match_Array(0)).Copy
                        mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midFPMS, 1).PasteSpecial

                        MSPS_RawWS.Range("A" & row_MSPS, "H" & row_MSPS).Copy
                        mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midMSPS, 11).PasteSpecial

                    ElseIf n_matches > 1 Then

                        For I = 0 To n_matches - 1

                            FPMS_RawWS.Range("A" & match_Array(I), "H" & match_Array(I)).Copy
                            mid_ReportWS.Range("A" & row_midFPMS + I).PasteSpecial

                        Next I

                        MSPS_RawWS.Range("A" & row_MSPS, "H" & row_MSPS).Copy
                        mid_ReportWS.Range("K" & row_midMSPS).PasteSpecial

                    End If

                    'Next free rows in mid-report
                    row_midMSPS = row_midMSPS + n_matches
                    row_midFPMS = row_midFPMS + n_matches

                    'The supreme_match_Array contains the row-position of all FPMS records that have been matched with an MSPS partner
                    'Empty the contents of the match_Array into the supreme array.
                    'The match_Array is recycled for every MSPS record - not every IMO number.

                    I = 0

                    Do Until match_Array(I) = 0

                        supreme_match_Array(I_sup) = match_Array(I)

                        I_sup = I_sup + 1
                        I = I + 1

                    Loop


                    'When the next MSPS record has a different IMO number than the current one, check supreme_match_Array against IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array
                    'to find out which FPMS records have not been paired with their MSPS counterparties, and copy these to the mid-report.
                    If IMO_next_match = False Then

                        temp_FPMS_Row = row_first_FPMS

                        IMO_matches = 0

                        'Find position of all FPMS records with matching IMO, and save this
                        Do While IMO_Number = FPMS_RawWS.Cells(temp_FPMS_Row, 1)

                            IMO_matches = IMO_matches + 1

                            IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(IMO_matches - 1) = temp_FPMS_Row

                            temp_FPMS_Row = temp_FPMS_Row + 1

                        Loop

                        supreme_Size = 0

                        Do While supreme_match_Array(supreme_Size) > 0 'Find size of array

                            supreme_Size = supreme_Size + 1

                        Loop


                        For I = 0 To IMO_matches - 1

                            For I_sup = 0 To supreme_Size - 1

                                If IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(I) = supreme_match_Array(I_sup) Then

                                    IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(I) = 0
                                    GoTo NextIteration_I

                                End If

                            Next I_sup
NextIteration_I:
                        Next I

                        For I = 0 To IMO_matches - 1

                            If IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(I) > 0 Then

                                FPMS_RawWS.Range("A" & IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(I), "H" & IMO_FPMS_Pos_Array(I)).Copy
                                mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midFPMS, 1).PasteSpecial

                                mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midFPMS, 9).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=mid_ReportWS.Cells(row_midFPMS, 9), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                               "'MSPS Raw'!A" & row_MSPS & ":R" & row_MSPS, TextToDisplay:="FPMS missing MSPS counter."


'                                Cells(row_midFPMS, 9).Select
'                                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
'                                "'MSPS Raw'!A" & row_MSPS & ":R" & row_MSPS, TextToDisplay:="FPMS missing MSPS counter."

                                row_midFPMS = row_midFPMS + 1

                                FPMS_noMatches = True

                            End If

                        Next I

                        If FPMS_noMatches = True Then

                            'Next free rows in mid-report
                            row_midMSPS = row_midFPMS

                            FPMS_noMatches = False

                        End If

                        'The supreme array should be purged since we are moving on to another IMO-number
                        ReDim supreme_match_Array(30)
                        I_sup = 0

                    End If

            ElseIf quantity_MSPS = True Then


                        Sheets("MSPS Raw").Activate
                        Range("A" & row_MSPS, "H" & row_MSPS).Copy
                        Sheets("Mid-Report").Activate
                        Cells(row_midMSPS, 11).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste

                        'Cells(row_midMSPS, 9) = "MSPS missing partner."

                        Cells(row_midMSPS, 9).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                        "'FPMS Raw'!A" & row_FPMS_lastMatch & ":R" & row_FPMS_lastMatch, TextToDisplay:="MSPS missing partner."

                        row_midMSPS = row_midMSPS + 1
                        row_midFPMS = row_midFPMS + 1

                        row_FPMS = row_FPMS_lastMatch + 1


            End If 'Match check
            End If 'Date check
            End If 'Quantity > 0 check
    End If 'Error 40: Stock Update
    End If 'Date format check

    row_MSPS = row_MSPS + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

EDIT: Changing the size of the datasets does not make any difference. It still only manages to reconcile 5-7 lines before crashing, regardless of the datasets consisting of over 6000 rows total, or only 200 rows total.

Comment: If you open up task manager, are there any processes sitting at a high percentage? What about page file usage? I'm afraid Excel just has a 'scalability' limit. I'm guessing you are loading a whole load of records out of a database (or a report runs off a database) then processing them in your Excel macro? It might be time to move the processing into a database as well.

Comment: Only 12% of the CPU is being used while Excel is hanging, and there is more than enough physical and virtual memory available.
You are partly correct about it importing data from a database, but that will not be the case until it is in production. As it is now I have just imported the datasets manually, so there is no interaction with a database, nor any I/O stuff going on.
I really hope that I haven't hit Excel's ceiling. The datasets are no more than 1700x4 and 4500x6 large.

And as I've mentioned, drastically reducing the size of the datasets makes no difference at all.

Comment: Given your suspicion of the data I suggest you put a 'kamikaze' line in your code that stops at an arbitrary record number, and keep altering this until you can verify that it is a specific record causing the issue. Alternatively it may not hang on the same record every time which would imply that it's not data based.

Comment: It is unfortunately not data-based. If I'm lucky I can sometimes shake Excel out of its slumber and trigger a debug error box (with an error message completely unrelated to my problem - something to do with the macro calling objects that have been disconnected because I told Windows to restart the application), which will let me look at how far it came before it crashed. The reason I know it isn't data-based is because I can continue stepping through the code from the last line before the crash.

Comment: So how do you shake Excel out of it's slumber? How do you know it's frozen and isn't just busy? Perhaps you could add a logging procedure to your code that writes a line to an external log file for every record (and every procedure for that matter). This is then independent of the Excel UI and you might get a different perspective.

Comment: What you describe seems like a phenomina I encounter whenever I write a long running macro in Excel 2010 (havn't seen it in earlier versions).  If so, I believe Excel hasn't actually crashed, evem though is displays 'not responding'.  Try just leaving it for a while to see if it eventually completes.  BTW your code looks like it will take a very long time to run due to the massive number of sheet/cell references in loops and nested loops (havn't analysed it fully, sorry TL;DR) Try redesigning your code to avoid these (eg using `variant arrays`) you will be amazed how much faster it will run

Comment: Some other thoughts: Are you turning off auto recalc? Have you tried turning off screenupdating (you probably can't see your status bar, but just try it). It might be worth removing frills (hyperlinks and status bar controls) to see if they are the issue. We had a  performance issue in one of our word macros and it turned out to be a network issue - down in the bowels of the templates it was trying to reference a server that no longer existed and this simply evidenced itself in a very large delay as it tried and failed to find a server. Stranger things have happened!

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.


Electric: I try to close Excel the normal way, at which point Windows opens a dialogue box about how it isn't responding and that I can try to restart the application if I want to. If I choose to do this and keep pressing CTRL + Break, it usually forces a debug msg box to open. Recalc, ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts are all false.
 

I am pretty confident that the macro isn't running in the background, because whenever I use the above method (after 10-20 minutes) it is still only as many rows into the datasets as it would have been without the waiting time.

Comment: Chris: How do you suggest that I make use of variant arrays? Load both datasets into each of their own arrays and use these in the loops instead of the sheets themselves?

Comment: I following Chris' suggestion of using variant arrays in my loops. I will come back to you once I figure out if it works or not.

Comment: Alright, I now use the variant arrays when reconciling the data sets, so there are very few sheet and cell references - but it still crashes at 1%.

Answer (score 0):

Ah Christ, I feel so stupid. I had accidentally removed the step-sentence from a Do While-loop. I apologize for wasting your time. My code now runs faster than it ever has, though, thanks to the variant arrays suggested by Chris.